# SQL Server 2005, turn columns into rows

Tags: sql, pivot

I am trying to turn a table 90 degrees: make columns rows.  No PIVOT is allowed since PIVOT requires aggregate functions.

Example: 
I have a table with the columns:
ID int,
ISO char(2),
Text varchar(255).

So I have this:

```
ID ISO Text
-- --- ----
 1 DE  Auto
 2 EN  Car
```

I'd like to get the following:

```
ID EN  DE
-- --- ----
 1 Car Auto
```

How do you accomplish that?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please clarify your example, and use spaces!

Comment: Shouldn't the second row of the first table be "1 EN Car"?

Comment: As interesting the question is, I suggest you describe what you are trying to achieve in the end.. I get the feeling you could solve whatever you're trying to do WITHOUT turning your table into a transposed monster.

Comment: Re-read the question, OP is trying to do a pivot query without a pivot.

Comment: +1 I had a similar problem yesterday

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you targetting? SQL2000, 2005, 2008, MySQL, Oracle..?

Comment: Kev, the title says SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Just to explain why I needed this functionality: we have teh table: Texts which has ID, ISO, Text columns. ID and ISO are PK and are unique.  When we want to ask the business for the translations we need to create a CSV user-friendly which is: ID, Text(EN), Text(DE). 

I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: This not a case of columns into rows but multiple rows in to combined row

Answer (score 5):

[This answer is really frantisek's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428041/sql-server-2005-turn-columns-into-rows#428344), I'm just copying here to correct the mistake (I can't edit directly).

Basically, you use that solution, with a tweak:

```
SELECT 
    max(DE) as DE, max(EN) as EN 
FROM 
    test 
PIVOT (MAX([text]) FOR ISO in (DE,EN)) p
```

This will get the content into a single row.  Also, it drops the ID, since it doesn't make sense if you want a single row (there is no logic to indicate what to do with it when combining into a single row).

Also, the assumption is made that the values in the ISO column are unique, otherwise, this will lose data due to the [`MAX` aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751(v=SQL.90).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution as the following:

```
SELECT 
    ID, DE, EN
FROM 
    TextTable 
PIVOT(MAX([text]) FOR ISO IN (DE,EN)) p
```

It's possible to use PIVOT with MAX aggregating function over the text.

Answer (score 1):

Query *without* a PIVOT even though other answers prove you *can* use a PIVOT :)

```
SELECT
    MAX(DE.Text) AS DE,
    MAX(EN.Text) AS EN  
FROM TextTable AS TT
LEFT JOIN TextTable AS DE
    ON DE.ID = TT.ID
    AND DE.ISO = 'DE'
LEFT JOIN TextTable AS EN
    ON EN.ID = TT.ID
    AND EN.ISO = 'EN'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try this solution and get a syntax error try setting the compatability mode of your database via

```
ALTER DATABASE myDatabase SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90;
```

This will set the compatability to SQLServer 2005 and the above queries will execute w/o a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
   t.num_claim_no,
   rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, t.txt_remarks ||'@'|| t.dat_update_date || '  ,  ')).extract ('//text()'), ',') Remarks,
   rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, t.num_update_no || ' , ')).extract ('//text()'), ',') SrlNo
from 
   gc_clm_gen_info t
   where t.txt_remarks is not null
  group by 
   t.num_claim_no
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you explicitly asked for a non-pivot solution: this should work, if you know which ISOs you will have in the rows. I called the table "Test".

```
declare @temp table ([ID] int, [de] varchar(255), [en] varchar(255)) -- add ISOs if necessary

INSERT @temp 
SELECT distinct [ID], '', '' from Test -- ADD '' for other ISOs if necessary

DECLARE c CURSOR read_only 
FOR SELECT [ID], [ISO], [Text] from test

DECLARE  @ID int, @ISO char(2), @Text varchar(255)
OPEN c

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ID, @ISO, @Text
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  @temp
        SET     [DE] = case when @ISO = 'DE' then @Text else [de] end,
            [EN] = case when @ISO = 'EN' then @Text else [en] end
                    -- add ISOs if necessary
        WHERE   [ID] = @ID
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @ID, @ISO, @Text
END

CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c

SELECT * FROM @temp
```