# Take data from multiple rows to a single row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks similar to this here:

```
DOCCODE  |  DOCDATE  |  STATUS    
001      | 10-OCT-13 |  START    
001      | 12-OCT-13 |  STOP    
001      | 15-OCT-13 |  START    
001      | 20-OCT-13 |  STOP    
002      | 01-NOV-13 |  START
```

I would like to try and have this output

```
DOCCODE   | STARTDATE  |  STOPDATE  | STATUS    
001       | 10-OCT-13  |  12-OCT-13 | STOP    
001       | 15-OCT-13  |  20-OCT-13 | STOP    
002       | 01-NOV-13  |            | START
```

Comment: Please stop posting in all uppercase - it looks like you are shouting at us. And please format your code - I'll do it this time for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005, turn columns into rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428041/sql-server-2005-turn-columns-into-rows)

Comment: Voted for close - the GROUP BY answer in the linked question should work for any RDBMS (doesn't require PIVOT or similar).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a self (outer) join

```
SELECT start.doccode AS doccode, 
       start.docdate AS startdate, 
       stop.docdate AS stopdate, 
       COALESCE(stop.status, start.status) AS status
FROM   my_table start
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_table stop ON start.doccode = stop.doccode
WHERE  start.doccode = 'START' AND stop.doccode = 'STOP'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select sr.DOCCODE
, sr.DOCDATE [STARTDATE]
, x.DOCDATE [STOPDATE]
, ISNULL(x.[STATUS], sr.[STATUS]) [STATUS]
from my_table sr
outer apply (
    select top 1 *
    from my_table sp
    where [STATUS] = 'STOP'
    and DOCDATE > sr.DOCDATE
    and DOCCODE = sr.DOCCODE
    order by DOCDATE) x
where sr.[STATUS]  = 'START'
```

---

Results:

```
DOCCODE STARTDATE   STOPDATE    STATUS
001     2013-10-10  2013-10-12  STOP
001     2013-10-15  2013-10-20  STOP
002     2013-11-01  NULL        START
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dbda0/1)

---

UPDATE

Oracle version (using correlated subqueries instead of **cross apply**):

```
select sr.DOCCODE
, sr.DOCDATE STARTDATE
, (
    select min(DOCDATE)
    from my_table sp
    where STATUS = 'STOP'
    and DOCDATE > sr.DOCDATE
    and DOCCODE = sr.DOCCODE) as STOPDATE
, NVL((
    select min(STATUS)
    from my_table sp
    where STATUS = 'STOP'
    and DOCDATE > sr.DOCDATE
    and DOCCODE = sr.DOCCODE), sr.STATUS) as STATUS
from my_table sr
where sr.STATUS  = 'START'
```

[SQL Fiddle (Oracle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6a39/1)

Comment: Whether this code work in Oracle Sql Developer

Comment: See update in the post

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s1.doccode AS doccode, 
   s1.docdate AS startdate, 
   s2.docdate AS stopdate, 
   isnull(s2.status, s1.status) AS status
FROM   my_table s1
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_table s2 ON s1.doccode = s2.doccode
WHERE  s1.doccode = 'START' AND s2.doccode = 'STOP'
```